How to merge similar photos
Say I have some images that are similar. In this case they are of cracked track pads on computers. Each picture ends up being taken from a slightly different angle so none of them match up perfectly. I want to be able to automatically scale and align the images so they line up correctly and then merge them.
I've added two example images here but I have about 20 to process.
Is there some automated way of doing this?



How do you expect to merge them? These images are from different subject...

yes, please explain the merging aspect of your task. What exactly are you trying to do here?

With Gimp you use the Perspective tool in "Corrective mode on the first picture: you make the tool guides follow pad outline, and when you hit Transform the pad is made rectangular:

For the next images you use the perspective tool in "normal" mode and drag the handles to make the corners match the corners of the first pad:


For both images it can be practical to first crop them to the area of interest.
For the images in "normal" mode you can make the layer partially transparent and use the "composited preview".
None of this will fix shadow direction

Result:

Remember that if you want to average images, the rule is that a layer opacity is 1/N of its position in the stack (from the bottom), so 100% (bottom), 50%, 33.3%, 25%, 20%, 16.7%, 14.3%, 12.5% etc...

I would use the guided perspective correction in Lightroom.  In the Develop module open the Transform tab and click guided.  Draw a line along each side of the trackpad and it will transform it to make the trackpad rectangular.  Then go to Photoshop and place guidelines to show where you want the final image.  Select the subject and Edit->Free Transform and make it the shape you want.  I am sure other editing software can do this, too, but these are the ones I know.  I use the guided transform when I photograph quilts to take out the perspective distortion.
